# What's the minimum SDK version for new iOS apps?

Tags: developer-program

Is there a page on the Apple website listing the minimum iOS SDK required for new app submissions?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The Apple Developer news feed is where Apple announces all hard deadlines on SDK requirements that are not enforced when you submit an app. Watching here, you can prepare for future requirements before they are enforced.

- https://developer.apple.com/news/

Today (October 2020) it’s the iOS 13 SDK and [iOS 14 was announced as the mandatory minimum in April 2021](https://developer.apple.com/ios/submit/).

> Starting April 2021, all iOS and iPadOS apps submitted to the App Store must be built with Xcode 12 and the iOS 14 SDK.

Find the News Link [here](https://developer.apple.com/news/?id=ib31uj1j).

Comment: Does anyone know what date in April. I am about to submit with some 3rd party runtime that was build using sdk13.

Comment: Does anyone have further information about what date in April this takes effect? Has the deadline already passed? I wish Apple would be a little more specific about these things

Comment: I have not heard of Apple rejecting apps yet not using iOS 14 SDK, so submit your code immediately if you haven’t finished work on the now old SDK (iOS 15 is coming to beta in less than 60 days from now @forresthopkinsa )

Comment: Is this only for new apps? or also includes old app updates?